# Why INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS does not list up materialized view in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, information-schema

I could not able to see materialized view while executing below query in Snowflake even though current role in session is owner role which has all the privileges on an object (here materialized view)

`Select * from MYDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`

Snowflake documentation mention following

> This Information Schema view displays a row for each view in the specified (or current) database, including the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views for the database.

Although while executing below command , I am able to see all the views including materialized views.

`Show Views in DATABASE MYDB`

Comment: Although it is not well documented, I find materialized views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'.

Comment: And the explanation behind Maja's is, a `VIEW` is just a conceptual layer of SQL, that is optimizer bolt in front of you SQL. Where-as a materialized view, is actually a new table, written and managed like other tables, that has it's own data/state. Thus although it's called a view, it's a magic table.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I need to get materialized view definition which I can't access from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view as there is no column which has materialized view definition. I think I have to use show command to access materialized view definition.

Comment: Alternatively I can use GET_DDL('VIEW','VIEW_NAME') to get definition of materialized views

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is a problem with the information_schema.views not listing the MV details. Instead of information_schema.views , the details are present in information_schema.tables (table_type column).

There is an improvement request already filed with the snowflake engineering team to correct this issue and include the MV details in the information_schema.views view. The improvement request has been approved however there is no ETA at this time. Please use the information_schema.tables view at this time to gather the required information.